# Delphi: Prompt for UAC elevation when needed

Tags: delphi, uac, elevation

We need to change some settings to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE at runtime.

Is it possible to prompt for uac elevation if needed at runtime, or do I have to launch a second elevated process to do 'the dirty work'?

Comment: I saw good article in the famous [Jedi](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/2008/03/18/elevate-application-on-vista-with-jwscl/) Lib too

Comment: The Jedi example for "elevating parts of an application" depend on a COM object, and calling into that. The downside of using a COM object is that you have to write a COM object, and even worse: register it on the user's computer. It is easier to pass yourself instructions on the command line, or in shared memory, or though a named pipe.

Comment: Using the command line to pass instructions is rather problematic if you have to use credentials or rather large amount of data.
A named pipe should not be used since it can be connected from nearly everywhere on the computer. Instead use the pipe handle and send it to the new process (it can inherit the handles by CreateProcess). Be careful with shared memory because it may open a vulnerability (mainly buffer overflow). The elevated process must carefully check the input.

Answer (score 27):

i would relaunch yourself as elevated, passing command line parameters indicating what elevated thing you want to do. You can then jump right to the appropriate form, or just save your HKLM stuff.

```
function RunAsAdmin(hWnd: HWND; filename: string; Parameters: string): Boolean;
{
    See Step 3: Redesign for UAC Compatibility (UAC)
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756922.aspx

    This code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.
}
var
    sei: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
    ZeroMemory(@sei, SizeOf(sei));
    sei.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
    sei.Wnd := hwnd;
    sei.fMask := SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT or SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
    sei.lpVerb := PChar('runas');
    sei.lpFile := PChar(Filename); // PAnsiChar;
    if parameters <> '' then
        sei.lpParameters := PChar(parameters); // PAnsiChar;
    sei.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL; //Integer;

    Result := ShellExecuteEx(@sei);
end;
```

The other Microsoft suggested solution is to create an COM object out of process (using the specially created CoCreateInstanceAsAdmin function). i don't like this idea because you have to write and register a COM object.

---

**Note:** There is no "CoCreateInstanceAsAdmin" API call. It's just some code floating around. Here's the Dephi version i stumbled around for. It is apparently based on the trick of prefixing a class guid string with the "**Elevation:Administrator!new:**" prefix when normally hidden code internally calls **CoGetObject**:

```
function CoGetObject(pszName: PWideChar; pBindOptions: PBindOpts3; 
      const iid: TIID; ppv: PPointer): HResult; stdcall; external 'ole32.dll';

procedure CoCreateInstanceAsAdmin(const Handle: HWND; 
      const ClassID, IID: TGuid; PInterface: PPointer);
var
   BindOpts: TBindOpts3;
   MonikerName: WideString;
   Res: HRESULT;
begin
   //This code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.
   ZeroMemory(@BindOpts, Sizeof(TBindOpts3));
   BindOpts.cbStruct := Sizeof(TBindOpts3);
   BindOpts.hwnd := Handle;
   BindOpts.dwClassContext := CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER;

   MonikerName := 'Elevation:Administrator!new:' + GUIDToString(ClassID);

   Res := CoGetObject(PWideChar(MonikerName), @BindOpts, IID, PInterface);
   if Failed(Res) then 
      raise Exception.Create(SysErrorMessage(Res));
end;
```

---

**One other question:** How do you handle someone running as standard user in Windows XP?

Answer (score 22):

You can't "elevate" an existing process.  Elevated processes under UAC have a different token with a different LUID, different mandatory integrity level, and different group membership.  This level of change can't be done within a running process - and it would be a security problem if that could happen.

You need to launch a second process elevated that would do the work or by creating a COM object that runs in an elevated dllhost.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756922.aspx gives an example "RunAsAdmin" function and a "CoCreateInstanceAsAdmin" function.

EDIT: I just saw "Delphi" in your title.  Everything I listed is obviously native, but if Delphi provides access to ShellExecute-like functionality you should be able to adapt the code from the link.

Comment: I will look into it. Delphi is native and provides full access to the win32 api, including ShellExecute( ). Tanks.

Answer (score 20):

A sample of [ready-to-use code](http://pastebin.com/w4X4pHpC):

Usage example:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows{....};

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure StartWait;
    procedure EndWait;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  RunElevatedSupport;

{$R *.dfm}

const
  ArgInstallUpdate     = '/install_update';
  ArgRegisterExtension = '/register_global_file_associations';

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := Format('IsAdministrator: %s',        [BoolToStr(IsAdministrator, True)]);
  Label2.Caption := Format('IsAdministratorAccount: %s', [BoolToStr(IsAdministratorAccount, True)]);
  Label3.Caption := Format('IsUACEnabled: %s',           [BoolToStr(IsUACEnabled, True)]);
  Label4.Caption := Format('IsElevated: %s',             [BoolToStr(IsElevated, True)]);

  Button1.Caption := 'Install updates';
  SetButtonElevated(Button1.Handle);
  Button2.Caption := 'Register file associations for all users';
  SetButtonElevated(Button2.Handle);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StartWait;
  try
    SetLastError(RunElevated(ArgInstallUpdate, Handle, Application.ProcessMessages));
    if GetLastError <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  finally
    EndWait;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StartWait;
  try
    SetLastError(RunElevated(ArgRegisterExtension, Handle, Application.ProcessMessages));
    if GetLastError <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  finally
    EndWait;
  end;
end;

function DoElevatedTask(const AParameters: String): Cardinal;

  procedure InstallUpdate;
  var
    Msg: String;
  begin
    Msg := 'Hello from InstallUpdate!' + sLineBreak +
           sLineBreak +
           'This function is running elevated under full administrator rights.' + sLineBreak +
           'This means that you have write-access to Program Files folder and you''re able to overwrite files (e.g. install updates).' + sLineBreak +
           'However, note that your executable is still running.' + sLineBreak +
           sLineBreak +
           'IsAdministrator: '        + BoolToStr(IsAdministrator, True) + sLineBreak +
           'IsAdministratorAccount: ' + BoolToStr(IsAdministratorAccount, True) + sLineBreak +
           'IsUACEnabled: '           + BoolToStr(IsUACEnabled, True) + sLineBreak +
           'IsElevated: '             + BoolToStr(IsElevated, True);
    MessageBox(0, PChar(Msg), 'Hello from InstallUpdate!', MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  end;

  procedure RegisterExtension;
  var
    Msg: String;
  begin
    Msg := 'Hello from RegisterExtension!' + sLineBreak +
           sLineBreak +
           'This function is running elevated under full administrator rights.' + sLineBreak +
           'This means that you have write-access to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE key and you''re able to write keys and values (e.g. register file extensions globally/for all users).' + sLineBreak +
           'However, note that this is usually not a good idea. It is better to register your file extensions under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes.' + sLineBreak +
           sLineBreak +
           'IsAdministrator: '        + BoolToStr(IsAdministrator, True) + sLineBreak +
           'IsAdministratorAccount: ' + BoolToStr(IsAdministratorAccount, True) + sLineBreak +
           'IsUACEnabled: '           + BoolToStr(IsUACEnabled, True) + sLineBreak +
           'IsElevated: '             + BoolToStr(IsElevated, True);
    MessageBox(0, PChar(Msg), 'Hello from RegisterExtension!', MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  end;

begin
  Result := ERROR_SUCCESS;
  if AParameters = ArgInstallUpdate then
    InstallUpdate
  else
  if AParameters = ArgRegisterExtension then
    RegisterExtension
  else
    Result := ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
end;

procedure TForm1.StartWait;
begin
  Cursor := crHourglass;
  Screen.Cursor := crHourglass;
  Button1.Enabled := False;
  Button2.Enabled := False;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

procedure TForm1.EndWait;
begin
  Cursor := crDefault;
  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  Button1.Enabled := True;
  Button2.Enabled := True;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

initialization
  OnElevateProc := DoElevatedTask;
  CheckForElevatedTask;
end.
```

And support unit itself:

```
unit RunElevatedSupport;

{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}
{$R+}

interface

uses
  Windows;

type
  TElevatedProc        = function(const AParameters: String): Cardinal;
  TProcessMessagesMeth = procedure of object;

var
  // Warning: this function will be executed in external process.
  // Do not use any global variables inside this routine!
  // Use only supplied AParameters.
  OnElevateProc: TElevatedProc;

// Call this routine after you have assigned OnElevateProc
procedure CheckForElevatedTask;

// Runs OnElevateProc under full administrator rights
function RunElevated(const AParameters: String; const AWnd: HWND = 0; const AProcessMessages: TProcessMessagesMeth = nil): Cardinal; overload;

function  IsAdministrator: Boolean;
function  IsAdministratorAccount: Boolean;
function  IsUACEnabled: Boolean;
function  IsElevated: Boolean;
procedure SetButtonElevated(const AButtonHandle: THandle);


implementation

uses
  SysUtils, Registry, ShellAPI, ComObj;

const
  RunElevatedTaskSwitch = '0CC5C50CB7D643B68CB900BF000FFFD5'; // some unique value, just a GUID with removed '[', ']', and '-'

function CheckTokenMembership(TokenHandle: THANDLE; SidToCheck: Pointer; var IsMember: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall; external advapi32 name 'CheckTokenMembership';

function RunElevated(const AParameters: String; const AWnd: HWND = 0; const AProcessMessages: TProcessMessagesMeth = nil): Cardinal; overload;
var
  SEI: TShellExecuteInfo;
  Host: String;
  Args: String;
begin
  Assert(Assigned(OnElevateProc), 'OnElevateProc must be assigned before calling RunElevated');

  if IsElevated then
  begin
    if Assigned(OnElevateProc) then
      Result := OnElevateProc(AParameters)
    else
      Result := ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND;
    Exit;
  end;


  Host := ParamStr(0);
  Args := Format('/%s %s', [RunElevatedTaskSwitch, AParameters]);

  FillChar(SEI, SizeOf(SEI), 0);
  SEI.cbSize := SizeOf(SEI);
  SEI.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  {$IFDEF UNICODE}
  SEI.fMask := SEI.fMask or SEE_MASK_UNICODE;
  {$ENDIF}
  SEI.Wnd := AWnd;
  SEI.lpVerb := 'runas';
  SEI.lpFile := PChar(Host);
  SEI.lpParameters := PChar(Args);
  SEI.nShow := SW_NORMAL;

  if not ShellExecuteEx(@SEI) then
   RaiseLastOSError;
  try

    Result := ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
    if Assigned(AProcessMessages) then
    begin
      repeat
        if not GetExitCodeProcess(SEI.hProcess, Result) then
          Result := ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
        AProcessMessages;
      until Result <> STILL_ACTIVE;
    end
    else
    begin
      if WaitForSingleObject(SEI.hProcess, INFINITE) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
        if not GetExitCodeProcess(SEI.hProcess, Result) then
          Result := ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
    end;

  finally
    CloseHandle(SEI.hProcess);
  end;
end;

function IsAdministrator: Boolean;
var
  psidAdmin: Pointer;
  B: BOOL;
const
  SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY: TSidIdentifierAuthority = (Value: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5));
  SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID  = $00000020;
  DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS      = $00000220;
  SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY  = $00000010;
begin
  psidAdmin := nil;
  try
    // Создаём SID группы админов для проверки
    Win32Check(AllocateAndInitializeSid(SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY, 2,
      SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      psidAdmin));

    // Проверяем, входим ли мы в группу админов (с учётов всех проверок на disabled SID)
    if CheckTokenMembership(0, psidAdmin, B) then
      Result := B
    else
      Result := False;
  finally
    if psidAdmin <> nil then
      FreeSid(psidAdmin);
  end;
end;

{$R-}

function IsAdministratorAccount: Boolean;
var
  psidAdmin: Pointer;
  Token: THandle;
  Count: DWORD;
  TokenInfo: PTokenGroups;
  HaveToken: Boolean;
  I: Integer;
const
  SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY: TSidIdentifierAuthority = (Value: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5));
  SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID  = $00000020;
  DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS      = $00000220;
  SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY  = $00000010;
begin
  Result := Win32Platform <> VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT;
  if Result then
    Exit;

  psidAdmin := nil;
  TokenInfo := nil;
  HaveToken := False;
  try
    Token := 0;
    HaveToken := OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread, TOKEN_QUERY, True, Token);
    if (not HaveToken) and (GetLastError = ERROR_NO_TOKEN) then
      HaveToken := OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, Token);
    if HaveToken then
    begin
      Win32Check(AllocateAndInitializeSid(SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY, 2,
        SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        psidAdmin));
      if GetTokenInformation(Token, TokenGroups, nil, 0, Count) or
         (GetLastError <> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) then
        RaiseLastOSError;
      TokenInfo := PTokenGroups(AllocMem(Count));
      Win32Check(GetTokenInformation(Token, TokenGroups, TokenInfo, Count, Count));
      for I := 0 to TokenInfo^.GroupCount - 1 do
      begin
        Result := EqualSid(psidAdmin, TokenInfo^.Groups[I].Sid);
        if Result then
          Break;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    if TokenInfo <> nil then
      FreeMem(TokenInfo);
    if HaveToken then
      CloseHandle(Token);
    if psidAdmin <> nil then
      FreeSid(psidAdmin);
  end;
end;

{$R+}

function IsUACEnabled: Boolean;
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Result := CheckWin32Version(6, 0);
  if Result then
  begin
    Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
    try
      Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
      if Reg.OpenKey('\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System', False) then
        if Reg.ValueExists('EnableLUA') then
          Result := (Reg.ReadInteger('EnableLUA') <> 0)
        else
          Result := False
      else
        Result := False;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(Reg);
    end;
  end;
end;

function IsElevated: Boolean;
const
  TokenElevation = TTokenInformationClass(20);
type
  TOKEN_ELEVATION = record
    TokenIsElevated: DWORD;
  end;
var
  TokenHandle: THandle;
  ResultLength: Cardinal;
  ATokenElevation: TOKEN_ELEVATION;
  HaveToken: Boolean;
begin
  if CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
  begin
    TokenHandle := 0;
    HaveToken := OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread, TOKEN_QUERY, True, TokenHandle);
    if (not HaveToken) and (GetLastError = ERROR_NO_TOKEN) then
      HaveToken := OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, TokenHandle);
    if HaveToken then
    begin
      try
        ResultLength := 0;
        if GetTokenInformation(TokenHandle, TokenElevation, @ATokenElevation, SizeOf(ATokenElevation), ResultLength) then
          Result := ATokenElevation.TokenIsElevated <> 0
        else
          Result := False;
      finally
        CloseHandle(TokenHandle);
      end;
    end
    else
      Result := False;
  end
  else
    Result := IsAdministrator;
end;

procedure SetButtonElevated(const AButtonHandle: THandle);
const
  BCM_SETSHIELD = $160C;
var
  Required: BOOL;
begin
  if not CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
    Exit;
  if IsElevated then
    Exit;

  Required := True;
  SendMessage(AButtonHandle, BCM_SETSHIELD, 0, LPARAM(Required));
end;

procedure CheckForElevatedTask;

  function GetArgsForElevatedTask: String;

    function PrepareParam(const ParamNo: Integer): String;
    begin
      Result := ParamStr(ParamNo);
      if Pos(' ', Result) > 0 then
        Result := AnsiQuotedStr(Result, '"');
    end;

  var
    X: Integer;
  begin
    Result := '';
    for X := 1 to ParamCount do
    begin
      if (AnsiUpperCase(ParamStr(X)) = ('/' + RunElevatedTaskSwitch)) or
         (AnsiUpperCase(ParamStr(X)) = ('-' + RunElevatedTaskSwitch)) then
        Continue;

      Result := Result + PrepareParam(X) + ' ';
    end;

    Result := Trim(Result);
  end;

var
  ExitCode: Cardinal;
begin
  if not FindCmdLineSwitch(RunElevatedTaskSwitch) then
    Exit;

  ExitCode := ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
  try
    if not IsElevated then
      ExitCode := ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
    else
    if Assigned(OnElevateProc) then
      ExitCode := OnElevateProc(GetArgsForElevatedTask)
    else
      ExitCode := ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      if E is EAbort then
        ExitCode := ERROR_CANCELLED
      else
      if E is EOleSysError then
        ExitCode := Cardinal(EOleSysError(E).ErrorCode)
      else
      if E is EOSError then
      else
        ExitCode := ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
    end;
  end;

  if ExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE then
    ExitCode := ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
  TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess, ExitCode);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, putting the text "Setup" or "Install" somewhere in your EXE name is enough to make Windows run with elevated privileges automatically, and is well worth doing if it is a setup utility you are writing, as it's so easy to do.

I am now running into problems though on Windows 7, when not logged in as an Administrator, and am having to use the right-click Run As Administrator when running manually (running the program via Wise installation wizard is still fine)

I see though that Delphi 10.1 Berlin has a very easy to use new option under Project Options | Application. Just tick Enable Administrator Privileges, and the manifest is done for you, so easy!

[image: Project Options]

NB. make sure you only do these kind of changes via a separate setup program, running your application with elevated privileges all the time can cause problems with other things, for example e-mail, where the default mail profile no longer gets picked up.

Edit: Jan 2018: since writing this answer in August 2017, it seems a lot of Windows updates have come out, that now require the user to right-click and Run As Administrator on just about everything, even on installation exe's built with Wise. Even Outlook is no longer installing properly without running as administrator. There is no more automated elevation at all it seems.

Comment: Windows has *heuristics* to try to catch poor developers who fail to add the mandatory  assembly manifest to their setup/installer executable (indicating `requireAdministrator`). Those heuristics can be turned off by group policy (as i do). The correct answer is to follow the Windows application rules: all executables must have an assembly manifest. At the same time: the correct way to install applications is through an MSI. The Windows Installer technology will then know **if** elevation is needed, and ask for it itself. But if you want your own setup.exe, you **must** have a manifest.