# How do I make a Delphi control panel applet be non-'legacy'?

Tags: delphi, controlpanel

I have a Delphi .CPL currently written with Delphi 7 which needs to update settings in HKLM (to be used by a service application) and which must support Vista, Win7 and Server 2008. Currently this can be done by adding a RUNASADMIN value to AppCompatFlags/Layers, using the CPL file as the value name. This causes Windows to ask for elevation for a 'legacy control panel applet'.

I need to find a way to build the CPL in Delphi 2010 without it appearing to be 'legacy' and, if possible, not to require the registry setting or elevation. Adding the usual manifest resource to the DLL/CPL referencing Common-Controls v6 and "requireAdministrator" does not fix the problem: no elevation is requested and HKLM access fails. Both the original and the Delphi 2010 .CPL can be made to run correctly (after elevation) by navigating to the file in SYSWOW64, right-clicking, and running 'as Administrator'.

Later: I have found a succint explanation of why you cannot elevate a DLL in this way in a forum posting [here](http://forums.techarena.in/vista-security/544931.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a better answer to my question. There *is* such an animal as a 'non-legacy' control panel applet, which is described in MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb757044.aspx). "Now, in Windows Vista, you can add your own applet to Control Panel by creating an executable for your applet and registering it, instead of going through the trouble of creating a .cpl file."

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use COM elevation.  There was a wonderful blog posting on this which appears to have been taken down, <strike>but the source code behind the posting is still [available](http://www.vclcomponents.com/go/41549/373536343e37343033613b663266366136613660306636393732323e36333332376136303e32343237323f313637363632653731343137613264323436353239373236353a66313033323f653338366533383332346537323664363237663634333233343b32313036663a353730333337323664313533313331363036323636373033323f32306636643e363633/)</strike> on the VCL components [website](https://web.archive.org/web/20101201042612/http://www.vclcomponents.com/Delphi/Other/Vista_UAC_COM_Elevation_Access_made_simple-info.html) (way back machine link).

Some additional information can be found in the question/answers for: [Delphi: Prompt for UAC elevation when needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923350/delphi-prompt-for-uac-elevation-when-needed/45751713)

Comment: Thanks, I think that solution would work and the code will be useful if I decide to do it that way.  But it may be simpler to abandon the idea of using a CPL and just do the service management with a regular EXE which can be elevated.

Comment: Either way you can use the mentioned method of COM elevation to elevate yourself "just in time" to apply your HKLM registry changes.

Comment: The links are down

Comment: There is a discussion on https://chapmanworld.com/2015/06/08/elevated-privileges-for-delphi-applications/ which may provide some additional light.  Keep in mind that we have shifted pretty far from Vista so some of the information you find may not work or need some additional help to get implemented.