# C++ Builder XE requested operation requires elevation

Tags: c++builder, uac

I've been using C++ builder XE under Windows 7 for a couple of years now. At some time I must have set the shortcut to C++ builder to "run as administrator", however I recently found that a bug which crashes my program when run from the command line (double clicking the .exe file in Windows Explorer) doesn't show itself in the IDE unless I DON'T run it as administrator. However, when I now pick another project I've been working on and try to compile and run it, I now get : "Error : Unable to create process: The requested operation requires elevation."
I realise this is due to Windows 7's UAC, but don't know how to debug my software any more !
Ideally, I would like to be able to compile and run my software in the debugger as a normal user.

Comment: Does your application use a COM Object which itself requires elevation?

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862786/newly-compiled-application-requires-uac-elevation?rq=1

Comment: WOW, EXCELLENT, AMAZING. Thanks, Roddy, the link helped me sort this out. My software had "Setup Software" as part of its description as it is used to set up a piece of hardware we manufacture. I've changed that (in Project/Options/Version Info) to User Software and now it compiles and runs ok !