# Windows7: Elevating permissions for one call

Tags: delphi, windows-7, uac, freepascal

I am working on an application (Windows XP and 7 - don't ask! ;) ) for the taskbar notification area. It is being started form user and admin accounts and usually does not need an elevated permission, I also don't want to bother every user with an UAC Dialog when the application is started.

Now I would like to integrate one call (write to the registry, HKLM) requiring elevated permissions and I wonder about the best strategy to implement this (in this case, in Delphi) for Windows 7+?

I have seen programs calling themselves with elevated permission and a parameter ([Delphi: Prompt for UAC elevation when needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923350/delphi-prompt-for-uac-elevation-when-needed/923551#923551)) - but is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Why do you need to write to HKLM which always requires admin privs? Can you not write to HKCU instead?

Comment: HKLM is required because it is a system-wide setting.

Comment: If it's a system wide setting, it should be written by the installer (which would require admin privileges to run) at the time of installation.

Comment: It is a system wide setting that can be changed by the administrator ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only elevate a process when the process is created. So that means you need to create a new process for this task.

When you need to perform elevated tasks, start a new process by calling `ShellExecuteEx` with the `runas` verb. Specify the tasks to be performed in the process command line.

If you can do this task at install time that is probably preferable.

Comment: This is one way to do it, and frankly it is the simplest way, but it is not the only way. Another way is to implement the desired admin tasks inside a COM object that the main app can then instantiate when needed using the [COM Elevation Moniker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687.aspx). This way, you don't have to spawn a separate process.

Comment: @Remy You do indeed spawn another process. The COM server runs in a separate process.

Comment: OK, let me re-phase then: "This way, you don't need to *explicitly and manually* spawn a separate process. The main app can use and communicate with the COM object as it would any other COM object."